Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'
My current flutter ver is Flutter 3.22.3
Hye when i run flutter i got this error
Below was on IOS
Error (Xcode): ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-7.4.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:669:56: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
Below was on Android
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-7.4.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:705:60: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'. color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color,

I dunno what had happened
i try everything
flutter clean
flutter pub get
i saw this one on log "1 package is discontinued."
is it because of this
! device_info_plus 8.0.0 (overridden) (10.1.1 available)?
flutter upgrade
nothing works
